# Regex in Yahoo Pipes: delete the Google prefixed part of the link

Tags: regex, yahoo-pipes

How do I get rid of the Google prefix to some of my links in this pipe?

http://pipes.yahoo.com/followtheboat/feedburner

I'm trying to strip out 'http://www.google.com/url?sa=X&q=' in some of the links, so I've tried the Regex rule:

In item.link replace http://www.google.com/url?sa=X&q= with [blank]

Where [blank] is where the text field is left empty. This doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the some of the characters in the regex; use `http://www\.google\.com/url\?sa=X\&q=` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Are you saying replace 'http://www.google.com/url?sa=X&q=' with 'http://www\.google\.com/url\?sa=X\&q='? Unless I am implementing this incorrectly this doesn't work when I use Regex on item.link.

Comment: @demonboy works for me, but regex `http://www\.google\.com/url\?sa=X&q=` - see [cloned pipe](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=1f68d44010c729931cc188df9700d431)

Comment: What is escaping the `&` supposed to do?  That’s not one of the exactly twelve regex metacharacters.

Comment: That's odd. If you compare your link for the story "FM : Govt never negotiates with Somalian pirates" with mine, yours is identical minus the google prefix, yet mine works and yours doesn't. I wonder if some of my links require the prefix in order to work? Anyway, with regards to my question and the response from TroutKing, this has been answered. Thank you both.